# how to change the order of columns after toggling in react-table

Tags: reactjs, react-table, react-table-v7

I have an issue with the order of the columns in react-table after toggling, and it goes like this example:
header of table :['first_name','last_name','gender','age']
when I toggle 'last_name' and toggle it back, it goes to its original index, not to the end of the array. I want the order to become after toggling : ['first_name','gender','age','last_name'] but it goes back to the first order instead.
How can I make it that whenever I toggle back a column it gets added to the end of the array not to its initial index?
PS: Im trying to achieve that so the user can import a csv with the desired order of columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [columns,setColumns] = useState(initialState)

// Function to Handle Toggle
const onToggleColumn = (column, index) => {
  const updatedColumns = columns.filter((col, i) => i !== index);
  updatedColumns.push(column);
  setColumns(updatedColumns);
};
```

And use it in React-Table like

```
<ReactTable
    columns={columns}
    onToggleColumn={onToggleColumn}
  />
```